# Android Widget/View LayoutParams how to get them?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using Android Giraffe and I want to get the LayoutParams from a button, then change one of the values, then set the new params, like so:

```
//get the current params
LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
//change something in the params
//set the button with the new params
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

However, "LayoutParams" is not an option by itself.  The options are specific to a view.  For example:

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
ViewGroup.LayoutParams
ActionBar.LayoutParams
etc...
```

Is one of these options supposed to work for just a Button?  There is no Button.LayoutParams.  How do accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  You just have to typecast the LayoutParams to the type of layout that the widget is within:

```
//get the current params and typecast to the parent layout type
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
//change something in the params
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 200);
//set the button with the new params
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: You can achieve the same effect with this single line:
    `button.setTranslationY(-200f);`

Answer (score 0):

I am just using this method to set params for the button or textview.

```
        fun button(button: Button, height: Int, width: Int, top: Int, bottom: Int, textSize: Int){
        val param = button.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        param.height = height
        param.width = width
        param.topMargin = top
        param.bottomMargin = bottom
        button.textSize = textSize.toFloat()
        button.setPadding(0,0,0,0)
    }
```